# Why are my Open-uri/Nokogiri requests taking longer (>30s) on my Heroku rails console than on my local rails console (<1s)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, web-scraping, nokogiri, open-uri

I have rails 4.2.1 installed.

On my local rails console:

```
2.2.1 :001 > require 'nokogiri'
=> true 
2.2.1 :002 > require 'open-uri'
=> true 
2.2.1 :003 > doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/fuo?srchType=T&query=knoll'))
```

And the response time is ~ 1s.

On the heroku rails console, I just run:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/fuo?srchType=T&query=knoll'))
```

And the response time is over 30s.

I get what I'm expecting in both places, but the response time on Heroku causes my app to time out in production.

Comment: You need to split this into two operations and see which part is slow. Is it fetching the content or parsing the result?

Comment: @tadman do you mean I should try something like:  doc = open('http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/fuo?srchType=T&query=knoll').read? to see if it's just the fetching of data that is slow?

Comment: Exactly. You need to isolate and investigate.

Comment: @tadman running `doc = open('http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/fuo?srchType=T&query=knoll').read` was just as slow. So it's the fetching of data. I'm at a loss as to why this would be so slow on the heroku console.

Comment: Next step is to hit up some other service than Craigslist. Is Google slow? How about http://example.com/?

Comment: It sounds like this isn't related to Nokogiri or Rails or web-scraping, and likely isn't about OpenURI either. Try using `curl` or `wget` and see what happens. Odds are really good it's nothing to do with code and is the environment, making all the tags invalid except "heroku".

Comment: @tadman thanks for the sanity check! I immediately assumed it was a problem with Heroku, since the fetching of Craigslist data is fast on my local rails console. But when I run: `doc = open('https://www.etsy.com/search?q=knoll%20furniture').read` in my heroku rails console, it's really fast. So it looks like the problem is the fetching of Craigslist data *from Heroku*. Seems strange, but not that far-fetched; I know they don't think twice about IP blocks, etc.

Comment: @theTinMan can you explain your rationale for thinking it's the environment and why curl or wget would fix it? The problem doesn't exist on my local rails console, where the environment is the same. And I just discovered other urls are working fine, so it seems to be the fetching of Craigslist data *from Heroku*.

Comment: `wget` or `curl` will test whether it's network IO, totally unrelated to Ruby or any gem or language, as those two run at the command-line. That's an important first test rather than spend time testing inside a language. That the problem doesn't exist locally also hints strongly that it's isolated to Heroku.

Comment: @Cbroph Maybe Craigslist has some kind of "go really slow if the request is from Heroku" filter added on to prevent automated scraping, or someone else has the same idea as you and is really abusing their site, resulting in some rate limits kicking in.